# Are there consequences to putting Application.Run() in a different Thread than the initial one?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I am currently trying my hand at .NET generic host stuff in combination with WinForms and am experimenting with something like this:

```cs
var mainmenu = new Thread(() => Application.Run(_mainMenuView as Form));
mainmenu.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
mainmenu.Start();
```

with _mainMenuView being an interface implemented by the MainMenuView Form which I get from DI yadayadayada.

My questions now are:

- Does this have unforeseen consequences?
- Do I need to join the Thread back to my "main" Thread?
- Does the Thread die if I just close the Form?
- How safe is it to get or set properties via the interface? Do I need to care about Invocation?

Thanks for helping

Comment: This is the same as if you would run it the main thread and then access form from another thread. So for example all UI interactions should go through dispatcher (Invoke).

Comment: I've done this to show splash screens during application startup without any issues (been doing it for more than a decade, so I probably would have noticed any problems by now!). However, the splash screens don't do very much and have little user interaction so YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been expirimenting with this also. You can run the `Application.Run` on another thread,

- Do I need to join the Thread back to my "main" Thread?
- How safe is it to get or set properties via the interface? Do I need to care about Invocation?

If you want to set any properties from a thread which is not the same as the application.run runs on. you should care about locking.

- Does the Thread die if I just close the Form?

The thread will finish when you close the form.

- Does this have unforeseen consequences?

One problem you will be facing is, the `Application` class uses static properties/methods. So you could get strange behavior when trying to create multiple threads with application.run on it.

Comment: Thats quite useful. Can you elaborate on locking? I have seen the keyword 'lock' before but not used it yet.
Application being static is also something I was concerned by but I have not seen anything weird yet, do you have some suggested precautions I should take?

Comment: Here is some info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement